# IOS/ASP.NET , Response.Redirect needs full absolute URI

Tags: asp.net, ios, asp.net-mvc-3, ipad, oauth

I have a quick question. In my asp.net code on server side, If I redirect by using just the target file name i.e Response.Redirect("Test.aspx") , it works on windows but not on IOS.
On IOS it gives the following error - Invalid Request / Bad URI.

But If i replace the uri with absolute uri ie.

### Response.Redirect("http://rediff.com/Test.aspx)

it works on both windows and IOS.

Thus in my code, I calculate the base uri and append the needed file for redirection.

Can you please clarify why this would work ?

-Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When client (browser) is provided with a relative URL, it will calculate the resulting URLs based on the base URL. So if the URL you want to redirect to is on the same domain, you can simply provide it the relative URL.

I've previously encountered caching issues when doing a 301 (Permanent) redirect on a URL which I then wanted to change to something else.